# How can I enable General PHP log and apache request log with MAMP 5.1

Tags: php, mamp-pro

I have this function that logs messages

```
function messageError($logDataJson, $file = null){
$logDataJson = is_string($logDataJson) ? $logDataJson : json_encode($logDataJson);
$logDataJson .= PHP_EOL;
$fe = fopen('php://stderr', 'w');
fwrite($fe, $file . $logDataJson );
```

}

when i run `messageError(['shop'=>"1"]);` i see the log message `{"shop":"1"}`

but when i run the script via http request i don't see the message in `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log` file.

in my `php.ini` it says
; Log errors into a log file (server-specific log, stderr, or error_log (below))
; As stated above, you're strongly advised to use error logging in place of
; error displaying on production web sites.
`log_errors = On`

what i want is to output message from `messageError(['shop'=>"1"]);` to `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log` file and to output `messageLoger(['shop'=>"1"]);` to `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php.log`

```
function messageLoger($logDataJson, $file = null){
$logDataJson = is_string($logDataJson) ? $logDataJson : json_encode($logDataJson);
$logDataJson .= PHP_EOL;
$fe = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fwrite($fe, $file . $logDataJson );
```

}

thanks any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`php://output` allow direct access to the corresponding output stream of the PHP process. to write to the log file, use `php://stderr`

alternatively, you can use the `error_log` function.

read more here : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

error_log function : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

---

example :

```
function log(...$vars): void 
{
     foreach($vars as $var) {
         error_log(sprintf('[LOG][%s] : %s', date('F j, Y, g:i a'), json_encode($var)));
     }
}

log('Hello');
log('a', 'b', 'c');
log([1,2,3]);
```

---

**UPDATE :**

since you are already using `php://stderr`, check your php.ini file and make sure that `error_log` is set to the log file.

example :

`error_log = /path/to/apache/php/log.txt`

if you want to log errors to syslog or Windows Server Event Log use `syslog`.

example :

`error_log = syslog`

Comment: thanks updated my question `messageError` to user `php://stderr` it was a typo thats what am using for that function and still does not write to `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log`

Comment: i have updated my answer , hope it helps.
in case you are still having the same problem , turn on all php error display and check if something else is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Enable `error_reporting(1)` and use `error_log()` function. That should solve your problem.